# iOS Swift 1.2: How to set a unique identifier for each cell aside from indexPath.row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm building an iOS app that has `Post` objects (like FB posts), and each one is displayed by a `UITableViewCell`. I'm trying to implement the ability to delete that post using the built in `tableView(commitEditingStyle)` method of the `UITableViewController`.

Temporarily I've been using the `indexPath.row` as the key for which post to delete, but obviously that will not work in the long run.

Is there a way to set some sort of unique identifier for each individual cell, ideally an integer equaling the index of the `Post` it contains?

Essentially I'm trying to create a One-to-One relationship with each `UITableViewCell` and its containing `Post`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass `UITableViewCell` and add a `postId` property to store the id of the associated post:

```
class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var postId: NSString? = nil

    func configure(post: Post) {
        postID = post.id
        // configure the labels, etc in the cell
    }
}
```

And then update to return this cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostTableViewCell") as? PostTableViewCell) ?? PostTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "PostTableViewCell")
    // assuming your posts are available in an array on your controller
    cell.configure(posts[indexPath.row])
    return cell
```

When an action is made on a cell (select, delete, etc), you can simply get it's associated post id and execute the desired action on the corresponding post with id.

This also has the advantage of reducing the complexity of the controller by moving away the cell configuration logic.

Comment: This should be the ideal way to go.